# Disconnected reconnect failed before timeout of x ms (transport close)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, google-chrome-headless

I have trouble running tests on Windows with the --no-sandbox flag. Without it, it works with no issues, but if not then I get the error

> Disconnected reconnect failed before timeout of x ms (transport close)

Within the docker it runs with no issues with --no-sandbox flag and without the flag it says that it's not supported or something like that.

Have you experienced such issues? How did you manage to solve them?

I checked most of the questions on stack and on the web, but it seems that nothing solves this issue.

I tried - setting additional, different flags, but none of the setups worked

I tried removing this flag - but that's needed in docker.

I tried updating all of the test libraries - nothing helps.

Here is my karma config

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

// this ensures we always have a fresh chrome copy
// and that it's usable in a ci/cd perspective
const process = require('process');

process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath()

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    debugMode: true,
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/Frontend'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    singleRun: true,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, you can have 2 scripts.

Try making the following changes:

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox', 'Chrome'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox']
      }
```

package.json

```
"test": "ng test --browsers ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox",
"test:windows": "ng test --browsers Chrome"
```

Something like that. Basically one script for the tests in Windows and another for the Docker/CI/CD.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I thought there is another way to make it work, yet this is a good idea.

I would go with an option to pass an argument to docker or something like that, but I need to figure out how to make it. Then if there is arg or env variable on - run npm `test-ci` option